# Ubuntu unattended upgrades stops Docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker

This is my current `50-unattended-upgrades` file:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
    "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
};

// List of packages to not update (regexp are supported)
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {};
Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease "false";
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";
```

A `containerd` upgrade was done early in the morning

```
2020-04-03 06:39:18,853 INFO Initial blacklisted packages:
2020-04-03 06:39:18,854 INFO Initial whitelisted packages:
2020-04-03 06:39:18,854 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2020-04-03 06:39:18,854 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates
2020-04-03 06:39:22,458 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: containerd
2020-04-03 06:39:22,458 INFO Writing dpkg log to /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log
2020-04-03 06:39:29,941 INFO All upgrades installed
```

Which caused `docker` to stop via Systemd.

```
Apr 03 06:39:23 ip-10-2-1-12 systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
Apr 03 06:39:23 ip-10-2-1-12 dockerd[3214]: time="2020-04-03T06:39:23.782508859Z" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
Apr 03 06:39:23 ip-10-2-1-12 dockerd[3214]: time="2020-04-03T06:39:23.933398454Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Apr 03 06:39:23 ip-10-2-1-12 dockerd[3214]: time="2020-04-03T06:39:23.945486871Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Apr 03 06:39:24 ip-10-2-1-12 dockerd[3214]: time="2020-04-03T06:39:24.155022784Z" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" e
rror="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Apr 03 06:39:24 ip-10-2-1-12 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Is there any way to override this behavior? I would prefer a `systemctl restart` rather than a `systemctl stop`.

Relevant data:

- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Docker 19.03.6 installed by `apt`

Comment: This should not happen as far as I know. There was a similar bug here that was fixed in a previous version: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io/+bug/1658691 — my systems with 18.04.4 and Docker 19.03.6 (installed via unattended upgrades) never required a manual Docker start.

Comment: Is your Docker installation configured to automatically start? https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot

Comment: @slhck, yes. The systemd unit is enabled. Actually, docker brings up automatically if I reboot the machine. Seems like unattended-upgrades is sending a stop signal to systemd.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I just observed the same issue (Docker daemon not starting after an apt update), but only on one system, not the other…

Comment: hi @slhck, no. For now I just disabled the automatic upgrades.

Comment: [Ubuntu fix-released this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/hirsute/+source/docker.io/+bug/1870514)